# how to convert string to time with format HH:MM AM/PM in JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, string-to-datetime

this will be my first time to use javascript as a part of my project. And i need to convert a string in format HH:mm AM/PM to a 24 hr format (00:00:00) time. Please help guys! Thank you in advance.

Comment: First split it into the parts (`time.split(/[\s:]/)` might do), then inspect the am/pm part and add 12 to the hours, or not, depending on what you find. Then return a formatted string with the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
var input   = '10:23 PM',
    matches = input.toLowerCase().match(/(\d{1,2}):(\d{2}) ([ap]m)/),
    output  = (parseInt(matches[1]) + (matches[3] == 'pm' ? 12 : 0)) + ':' + matches[2] + ':00';

console.log(output); // 22:23:00
```

Comment: Thank you sir, but how about an input of "6:45 PM"? What's the best way to determine the input of user either "6:45 PM or 10:56 AM"? You code sir running successfully for 06:23 AM and not with 6:23 AM. Thanks Sir.

Comment: @Aljie You're right. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you Sir @hsz :)) It saves a lot for me now :)

Comment: what if time lies between 12:00 AM to 12:59 AM